What XSLT is needed to extract and transform this specific XHTML?
I'm trying to extract a subset of some HTML from a larger file and then perform a few transformations of the result. I've made some progress but I'm missing a piece or two to make this work as desired.
Here is a greatly simplified version of the XHTML I wish to transform:
<html>
<head>
<!-- lots of stuff I don't care about -->
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <!-- lots of stuff I don't care about -->
  <div>
     <!-- lots of stuff I don't care about -->
     <div id="key_div">
         <div id="ignore_this">
           <!-- lots of stuff I don't care about -->
         </div>
         <p>More junk I don't want</p>
         <p>Even more junk I don't want</p>
         <h2><span class="someClass" id="someID">Header</span></h2>
         <p>Stuff I want to keep</p>
         <!-- A lot of stuff I want to keep -->
         <p>More stuff I want to keep</p>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="/some/old/path">Fun Place</a></li>
           <li><a href="/some/old/other">Better Place</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <!-- lots of stuff I don't care about -->
  </div>
  <!-- lots of stuff I don't care about -->
</div>
</body>
</html>

I want to extract everything from the <h2> tag through the rest of the content inside the <div> with the id of "key_div". But I also want to transform the <h2> into a simpler <h1> and I need to modify the hrefs in the list. The final result should look like this:
<html>
<head>
<!-- My own header stuff -->
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Header</h1>
 <p>Stuff I want to keep</p>
 <!-- A lot of stuff I want to keep -->
 <p>More stuff I want to keep</p>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="/new/path">Fun Place</a></li>
   <li><a href="/new/other">Better Place</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>

I was able to do most of the basic extraction without any of the desired transformations by using the following XSL:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
     <title>My Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@id='key_div']/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@id='ignore_this']"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

This results in:
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>More junk I don't want</p>
<p>Even more junk I don't want</p>
<h2><span class="someClass" id="someID">Header</span></h2>
<p>Stuff I want to keep</p>
<p>More stuff I want to keep</p>
<ul>
           <li><a href="/some/old/path">Fun Place</a></li>
           <li><a href="/some/old/other">Better Place</a></li>
         </ul>
</body>
</html>

I don't know how to remove the stuff before the <h2>.
I don't know how to transform <h2><span class="someClass" id="someID">Header</span></h2> into <h1>Header</h1> or how to transform the hrefs. All of my attempts to combine a transform with the extraction usually ends up with no content.
There will be a few other transformations I need to perform but for now I'll focus on this example to get me started. I mention it so any possible answers don't prevent any other possible transformations.

Try something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/html">
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- your own header stuff -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//div[@id='key_div']/h2"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h2">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@href">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:text>/new/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '/old/')" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Assuming the HTML input elements are in no namespace (as in your samples although you speak about XHTML) it suffices to use the identity transformation (declared in XSLT 3 through <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>) plus templates for the body, the h2, the h2/span and the href attribute:
  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//div[@id = 'key_div']/h2/(., following-sibling::node())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h2/span">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul/li/a/@href">
    <xsl:attribute name="{node-name()}" select="replace(., '/some/old', '/new')"/>
  </xsl:template>

Using XSLT 2/3, XPath 2/3 in some places, XSLT 1/XPath 1 is
  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="h2" select=".//div[@id = 'key_div']/h2"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$h2 | $h2/following-sibling::node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h2/span">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul/li/a/@href">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('/new', substring-after(., '/some/old'))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

With the identity transformation added it would be
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="h2" select=".//div[@id = 'key_div']/h2"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$h2 | $h2/following-sibling::node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="h2/span">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ul/li/a/@href">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('/new', substring-after(., '/some/old'))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


I'm on macOS and the first solution gave me errors. The second solution ran but stripped out most of the HTML tags leaving just the body tags, the added h1 tags, and some text. Everything else was gone.

@HangarRash, well, you need to spell out the identity transformation as a template or set up your template matching /, I only posted the stuff that needs to be added/changed compared to your intent.

Sorry but I don't know what you mean. I just tried 3 different ways to integrate your suggestion into mine but it's not working. If you could update your 2nd example to be complete then that would be very helpful.

Thanks for the full example. It's much better. It even keeps the comments. The only issue is that it leaves all of the unwanted stuff inside the <head> tag instead of creating the new <head> content.
